# VS Load Test and 'Total Bytes Sent' Performance Counter?

Tags: benchmarking, load-testing, perfmon, performancecounter

I have a load test for a WCF service, where we are trying out different compression libraries and configurations and we need to measure the total number of mb sent during a test. Is there a performance counter that measure the relative trafic pr. test. If so, how do I add it to my load test - it seems that only a fraction of the performance counters are visible - E.g. under the category "Web Service", i don't see the performance counter "Total Bytes Received" in VS Load test, but I can find it in PerfMon.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, guess not many needed this information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the load test  expand Counter Sets > Expand applicable > Right Click on Counter Sets > Add Counters

You can implement your own custom performance counter like so:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace PerfCounter
{
class PerfCounter
{
    private const String categoryName = "Custom category";
    private const String counterName = "Total bytes received";
    private const String categoryHelp = "A category for custom performance counters";
    private const String counterHelp = "Total bytes received on network interface";
    private const String lanName = "Local Area Connection"; // change this to match your network connection
    private  const int sampleRateInMillis = 1000;
    private const int numberofSamples = 200000;

    private static NetworkInterface lan = null;
    private static PerformanceCounter perfCounter;
    private static long initialReceivedBytes;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        setupLAN();
        setupCategory();
        createCounters();
        updatePerfCounters();
    }

    private static void setupCategory()
    {
        if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName))
        {
            CounterCreationDataCollection counterCreationDataCollection = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
            CounterCreationData totalBytesReceived = new CounterCreationData();
            totalBytesReceived.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems64;
            totalBytesReceived.CounterName = counterName;
            counterCreationDataCollection.Add(totalBytesReceived);
            PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(categoryName, categoryHelp, PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance, counterCreationDataCollection);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Category {0} exists", categoryName);
    }

    private static void createCounters()
    {
        perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName, false);
        perfCounter.RawValue = getTotalBytesReceived();
    }

    private static long getTotalBytesReceived()
    {
        return lan.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
    }

    private static void setupLAN()
    {
        NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterface in interfaces)
        {
            if (networkInterface.Name.Equals(lanName))
                lan = networkInterface;
        }
        initialReceivedBytes = lan.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
    }

    private static void updatePerfCounters()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofSamples; i++)
        {
            perfCounter.RawValue = getTotalBytesReceived();
            Console.WriteLine("received: {0} bytes", perfCounter.RawValue - initialReceivedBytes);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sampleRateInMillis);
        }
    }
}
}
```